# Orbits of a matrix group

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, magma-cas, orbit-stabilizer

How to get the orbits of the action of the following matrix group on the standard basis of a 3-dim vector space?
\begin{pmatrix}
SL_2(2) & 0\\
* & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}

where * denotes a 1$\times$2 matrix with arbitrary entries in the field of 2 elements.

I suppose there are two orbits, one the zero vector and the other consisting of all other vectors?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the orbits under your group action, or how to obtain those orbits in Magma?

Comment: I tried to determine the orbits first. I suppose there are 2 orbits, one is (0,0,0)$^T$ and the other is the rest of the vectors, if I got it right. Then I want to see if I am correct by trying to construct the matrix group in Magma, hence the question.

Comment: No, $\{(0,0,1)^T\}$ is also an orbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is the matrix group actin on vector space $V$, you can get the orbit of $G$ on a specific vector $v\in V$ with $\mathtt{Orbit(G,v)}$.

I don't think there is a single command to return all of the orbits. An easy way to do this is

$\mathtt{\{Orbit(G,v): v\ in\ V\}}$,

although that would not be very efficient when $V$ is large.

You can construct the group as follows:

```
X := SL(3,2);
V := VectorSpace(X);
G := Stabilizer(X, sub<V|V.1,V.2> );
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the input. I'm still not sure how to construct the matrix group in order to do some orbit computation. Thx..

Comment: That is a different question. You asked how to find the orbits, not how to construct the matrix group.

Comment: OK. I will ask another question. Thx.

Comment: Don't bother, I've given the construction now.

Comment: appreciate the help.

Comment: By the way, I suppose the command "Orbits(G)" can give all the orbits of G for a matrix group? or I am being silly , again?

Comment: Yes that works!